# python list iteration with boolean

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, boolean

```
class_abbrevs_2 = [x.text for x in subject_page.find_all('td')[1].find_all('a')]
```

I am going through opening each link and then here is the page that is giving me the problem. It only has the one `'td'`, this has only a single td:

```
http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4168/CTIH/index.shtml
```

and here is what a normal page looks like that has 2 `'td'`:

```
http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4168/CSCI/index.shtml
```

Can someone tell me how I can run this line only if it's true. I can't figure out the syntax. Just for a little background if needed I am webscraping with python and BS4. Lmk if there is any other info that would help. Thanks

Comment: "only if it's true" <-- Only if what's true?

Comment: only if the element ('td')[1] is true or in other words only if the second ('td') element is present in the html

Comment: would I have to set it in a lambda function?

Comment: I think there's some confusion. `...('td')[1]` isn't a boolean, right? So it's not true or false. Either the list has at least two elements in it or it doesn't. If that element is there, it's some sort of HTML element, not a boolean. See my answer and let me know if that does what you want.

Comment: I imagine there is a much better way to get what you want, can you share the html?

Comment: I am going through opening each link and then here is the page that is giving me the problem. It only has the one ('td') http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4168/CTIH/index.shtml and here is what a normal page looks like. This has 2 ('td') http://registrar.indiana.edu/browser/soc4168/CSCI/index.shtml

Comment: @joedirt Personally, I'd look for the `div` with the ID `crsebrowser` and find `a` tags in there. Both pages seem to have exactly one of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly from the comment above, I think you just want this?

```
tds = subject_page.find_all('td')
if len(tds) > 1:
    class_abbrevs_2 = [x.text for x in tds[1].find_all('a')]
```

Comment: Yeah, that worked and yes I can see what you're saying. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the code to a select using *nth-of-type* to look for a second *td*:

```
text = [a.text for a in soup.select("#crsebrowser  td:nth-of-type(2) a")]
```

If there is no second td inside the table then it will find nothing so you with end up with a list of text from the anchors or nothing so you don't need any other logic to get the data.